# Pytest parallel can I run test after all parallel finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-xdist

I use Pytest to run 20 tests, and I config them to run parallel 5 each time

I need to run the final test that runs only when those 20 are finished, and I can't find a way to do it.

I tried xdist, and xdist group and didn't manage to succeed.

thanks